# How to get variable from request in nodejs module

Tags: node.js, callback, request

I have the following two files and can't get the result out of my modules request into the var inside `app.js`.

I thought about `module.exports` exports as callbacks but I can't find the right combination.

// app.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// i am a nodejs app
var Myobject = require('./code.js');

var value1 = "http://google.com";

var results = Myobject(value1); // results should stare the results_of_request var value 

console.dir(results); // results should stare the results_of_request var value
```

now comes the module
// code.js

```
// i am a nodejs module
module.exports = function(get_this) {
  var request = require('request');
    var options = {
          url: get_this,
    };



  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
               // we got no error and request is finished lets set a var
               var result_of_function = '{"json":"string"}'
            }
    }
// the main problem is i have no way to get the result_of_function value inside app.js
}
```

Comment: Only for Documentation i asked this question because many People that are new to JavaScript are not familar with the Callback Pattern if they don't heard about that befor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your exported function from your module is asynchronous, you need from your app to handle its result via a callback
In your app:

```
Myobject(value1, function(err, results){
  //results== '{"json":"string"}'
});
```

In your module:

```
module.exports = function(get_this, cbk) {
  var request = require('request');
    var options = {
          url: get_this,
    };

  request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
               return cbk(error);
             }
             // we got no error and request is finished lets set a var
             var result_of_function = '{"json":"string"}'
             return cbk(null, result_of_function)
    }
// the main problem is i have no way to get the result_of_function value inside app.js
}
```